# How to Edit\modify Batch file properties?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a set of batch files. on right click-properties -> detail, we see different attributes of file. like filename ,description, author, date modified. 
I want to edit these details and also want to add some new attributes.
How it can be done.
Is there any way that based of single file like Assemblyinfo.cs file in cs project, if we edit that it will change details on bat file.

Comment: Just add it as a comment at the bottom of the file.  The batch system doesn't have to go through a whole bunch of rem statements when it starts executing and it is the first thing you see when you type the file on a cmd prompt and the rest of the file has scrolled off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Batch files do not have a version resource like C/C++/C# applications compiled with a version resource added to the project. They are just plain text files.

What you see on **Details** tab are the information stored in (NTFS) file system for this file. You can see the same on .txt or .cs file.

There is no `author`, there is `owner`, i.e. who has created the file if not changed later via **Security - Advanced - Owner**.

You can only add credentials into the batch file at top as comment or output them with command **echo** on every script execution.

Comment: @Mofii:  How to edit those details ? how to add \remove attributes shown on 'Details' tab

Comment: @sagar It would be best if you edit your question and add a screen shot of what you are talking about. And please add also the version(s) of Windows on which you want to modify the data. I suppose you mean file summary information which can be added on a file/folder on an NTFS drive with an [alternate data stream](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105763). Modifying those informations with native batch commands is not possible as far as I know. But search in WWW for methods editing file summary information.